# Where charindex not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the query, it is returning zero matches:

```
select * 
from CompleteSet
where CHARINDEX(CompleteSet.Problem,'aaa') > 0
```

I know that I definitely have entries with `aaa` in `CompleteSet`.

I cannot figure out what is going on.

Comment: I don't believe you.  Show examples on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got it backwards, characters you're looking for are the first parameter:

```
select * from CompleteSet
where CHARINDEX('aaa',CompleteSet.Problem) > 0
```

Per MSDN link helpfully added in comments:

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

Square brackets indicate optional parameters.